# K8s DNS resolves the Route53 domain internally if the ingress is defined

Tags: kubernetes, dns, amazon-route53, nginx-ingress, coredns

The following chain describes how Pods that define an API are reached from the outside.

```
Client -> Route53 (.example.com) 
  -> LoadBalancer -> Nginx 
    -> Service -> Pod
```

Some pods, in addition to defining an API, communicate and use the API of others in the same cluster k8s.  To allow communication between pods I can do it using the internal dns: eg. `api1.ns.svc.cluster.local` or using the Route53 `api1.example.com` domain.

The first case is more efficient but on the other hand I need to keep a list of the necessary services and namespaces for each pod.

The second case is easier to manage.  I know that each API responds to `* .example.com` so I only need to know the subdomain to call.  This approach is extremely inefficient:

```
Pod1 -> Route53 (api2.example.com) 
  -> LoadBalancer -> Nginx 
    -> Service -> Pod2
```

In this scenario I would like to know if there are known solutions for which a pod to communicate with another can use the same domain managed by Route53 but without leaving the cluster and maintaining internal traffic.

I know I can use a core dns rewrite but in that case I should still keep an updated list, also Route53 holds subdomains pointing to services outside the cluster, e.g. `db.example.com`

So the idea is an autodiscovery of the ingress and keep internal traffic if possible:

```
Pod1 -> k8sdns with api2.example.com ingress 
  -> Nginx -> Service 
    -> Pod2
```

Or

```
Pod1 -> k8sdns without db.example.com ingress
  -> Route53 -> LoadBalancer 
    -> DB
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of anything off the top of my head, but it would be fairly trivial to write a pod the watches ingress/service resources and keeps a list, gets hacky real quick as you'd need to use something like dnsmasq and update teh resolv conf in pods.

Doable. But keeping a list is alot less effort IMO.

Comment: Have you considered service-discovery solutions? such as Consul?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it using the CoreDNS `rewrite plugin`. This is the [official documentation](https://coredns.io/plugins/rewrite/) and I'll give you an example how to implement it.

1. Edit the CoreDNS ConfigMap

```bash
kubectl edit cm -n kube-system coredns
```

2. Add this line inside the config:

```yaml
rewrite name regex (.*)\.yourdomain\.com {1}.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Your `cm` is going to look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           upstream
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        rewrite name regex (.*)\.yourdomain\.com {1}.default.svc.cluster.local
        prometheus :9153
        proxy . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

3. Save the edit and delete your CoreDNS pods

```bash
kubectl delete pod -n kube-system --selector k8s-app=kube-dns
```

4. And test it inside a dummy pod or query directly to the CoreDNS

```bash
# dig app1.yourdomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.33-Debian <<>> app1.yourdomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51020
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: c06f814fbf04a827 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;app1.yourdomain.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
app1.default.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN   A   10.110.113.195

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 10.96.0.10#53(10.96.0.10)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 26 04:49:47 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

Comment: thank you very much, but this configuration fails to handle the case where the service is not in cluster.  es db.example.com will be resolved to db.  default.svc.cluster.local.  I would like it to be resolved by Route53 if not found.  I could do this by declaring "exceptions" in coredns config but I should keep a list which in a production scenario is difficult to maintain

Comment: Ok, why would you do that? but anyway, for that particular case you may think about 3 options. 1- Use the coredns alternate plugin. https://coredns.io/explugins/alternate/ but is not installed by default on Kubernetes. 2- use a different domain name for your external or internal services and make a forward rule to your route53. 3- See if AWS has a default integration with route53 and manage all the domain names from there.